# ansible task with tag 'never' inside role executed when the role is executed using another tag

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have a playbook which has three roles `netdata`, `netdata_master`, `netdata_slaves`:

```
---
- hosts: netdata_master
  become: yes
  roles: 
    - role: netdata
    - role: netdata_master
  tags: ['netdata_master']

- hosts: netdata_slaves
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role: netdata
    - role: netdata_slave
  tags: ['netdata_slave']
```

Inside the `netdata` role I have a task which has tag `never` and `update_netdata` in order to be executed only when I pass the tag `update_netdata`:

```
- name: Generating Netdata prebuilt script
  template:
    src: kickstart-static64.sh.j2
    dest: /tmp/kickstart-static64.sh
    mode: 0744
- name: update netdata
  shell: /opt/netdata/usr/libexec/netdata/netdata-updater.sh
  tags: ['never', 'update_netdata']
```

The problem is when I execute the ansible playbook with no tags, everything works fine and `update netdata` is not executed but when I run the ansible playbook with `netdata_slave` tag, the `update netdata` task also gets executed.

I'm using ansible 2.9.2

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

> Q: *"When I run the ansible playbook with `netdata_slave` tag, the `update netdata` task also gets executed."*

A: This works as expected. Quoting from [Tag Inheritance](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance):

> Adding tags: to a play, or to statically imported tasks and roles, adds those tags to all of the contained tasks.

The directive `tags: ['netdata_slave']` **adds this tag to all of the contained tasks** of the `role: netdata`

```
  roles:
    - role: netdata
  tags: ['netdata_slave']
```

This makes the task to look effectively

```
- name: update netdata
  shell: /opt/netdata/usr/libexec/netdata/netdata-updater.sh
  tags: ['never', 'update_netdata', 'netdata_slave']
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do it with `tags:`, because the tag inheritance will override `never`.

However, you could do it in a sneaky way, by checking if the desired tag is in `ansible_run_tags`:

```
- name: Generating Netdata prebuilt script
  template:
    src: kickstart-static64.sh.j2
    dest: /tmp/kickstart-static64.sh
    mode: 0744
- name: update netdata
  shell: /opt/netdata/usr/libexec/netdata/netdata-updater.sh
  when: "'update_netdata' in ansible_run_tags"
```

Alternatively you could test a boolean variable (not tag) like

```
- name: update netdata
  shell: /opt/netdata/usr/libexec/netdata/netdata-updater.sh
  when: update_netdata | d() | bool
```

where the `d()` filter ensures this returns false if `update_netdata` is undefined.

The downside of this technique is that unlike a missing tag, a false conditional will still show up as 'skipped'. That isn't too bad in your case, but it works poorly for a common use case: hiding `debug` statements.